# How to Integrate FCM in nextjs. Can we manage the server side events of the fcm in nextjs server side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I want to integrate the FCM in my next js App. is it possible to handle both client side and server side modules in server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. we can manage both server and client-side modules in the next js. I've not experience in FCM but I've managed the redis on next server side. If we can mange the Redis then Hope so we can manage this